# Узнать быстро в Visual Studio, возможные передаваемые типы под маской интерфейса

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper

Допустим, имеется некоторый интерфейс, который реализует сотня классов.

Есть метод, который принимает на вход этот интерфейс и в коде есть только 2 ссылки на него.

Можно ли с помощью VS быстро узнать, какие реальные типы передаются в коде в данный метод?

Или все таки единственный вариант- это интерактивно идти по коду вверх пока я не найду тот самый тип?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Поставить брейкпоинт и поглядеть передаваемый тип? Или найти все имплементации интерфейса?

Comment: Есть процедура, которая принимает интерфейс. Узнать, какие реальные типы могут дойти до этой процедуры, зная методы которые ссылаются на эту процедуру.

Comment: так процедуру можно и через рефлексию или AOP вызывать, как и параметры кастовать к чему попало. Никакая ИДЕ 100% не подскажет, какие типы реально могут туда передаваться.

Comment: @tym32167, рефлексия понятно- это штука мощная и непредсказуемая, но речь идет о коде, который имеется в проекте без учета всяких внешний рефлексий.

Comment: Да я к тому, что никак не узнать. Только дебаг и прогулки по коду.

Comment: как узнать какие значения попадут в параметр типа int в процедуре? Ваш вопрос из той же серии. Если процедура используется в замкнутой среде, то проходом по коду, интерактивно или методом "пристального вглядывания" в код вызова процедуры, если в незамкнутой - никак.

Comment: @rdorn, мне кажется, что в замкнутом коде все таки вполне реально найти все возможные передаваемые значения в функцию автоматически. Странно, что никто не сделал такую штуку, ведь она бы облегчила изучение чужого кода.

Comment: в теории да, но по факту это потребует фактически выполнить программу, да еще и по всем возможным сценариям. Из доступных средств студии - можно найти все места вызова метода (View Call Hierarchy), а дальше уже точечно исследовать вызывающие методы. Возможно потребуется пройти по всему дереву вызовов. Что-то похожее умеют делать статические анализаторы.

Comment: @rdorn, а зачем ее выполнять? Даже условия анализировать не нужно. По сути анализатор, должен мысленно удалить все условия и подобные штуки и работать с линейном списком вызовов методов и объявлений.

Comment: @iluxa1810 "мысленно удалить все условия и подобные штуки" это и есть самая сложная часть работы. А если не секрет, зачем такое понадобилось? Интерфейс ведь и предназначен для того, чтобы не думать что именно передали в параметр. Если понадобился каст к исходному классу - это уже не совсем нормально и надо что-то менять.

Comment: @rdorn, да просто люблю поизучать чужой код, а из-за обилия интерфейсов бывает тяжело восстановить логику, так как много держать в голове приходится.

Comment: @iluxa1810 попробуйте отобразить интересующий метод на code map со всеми зависимостями в студии, иногда помогает распутать клубок, иногда правда становится еще хуже =)